# SNMP Security Error

Tags: snmp

Getting security error regarding snmp, from Security Metrics.

Running Centos 5.7 64bit. + Cpanel (snmp not compiled in easyapache)
2.6.18-274.17.1.el5

Risk: 10

```
Description: SNMP is enabled and may be vulnerable Severity: Potential Problem CVE: CVE-2002-0012 CVE-2002-0013 CVE-2002-0053 Impact: If a vulnerable implementation of SNMP is running, a remote attacker could crash the device, cause the device to become unstable, or gain unauthorized access. Resolution For the HMAC length 1 security bypass vulnerability, [http://www.net-snmp.org/download.html] update to NET-SNMP 5.4.1.1, 5.3.2.1, 5.2.4.1, 5.1.4.1, 5.0.11.1, or UCD-snmp 4.2.7.1 or get updates for other products from your vendor. There are a number of measures which can be taken to reduce the risk of this vulnerability being exploited. Apply a [http://www.cert.org/advisories/CA-2002- 03.html#vendors] patch from your vendor if one is available. (IRIX users should also refer to [ftp://patches.sgi.com/support/free/secur ity/advisories/20020201-01-P] SGI Security Advisory 20020201-01-P, and Sun users should also refer to [http://sunsolve.sun.com/pub-cgi/retriev e.pl?doc=secbull/219] Sun Security Bulletin 219 for patch information.) Change all community strings to non-default strings which are difficult to guess. Block access to UDP ports 161 and 162 at the network perimeter. Disable the SNMP service on machines where it can be disabled and is not needed. There are a number of additional precautions which should also be taken wherever possible: Filter SNMP traffic from unauthorized internal hosts Segregate SNMP traffic onto a separate management network Block incoming and outgoing traffic (ingress and egress filtering) on ports 161, 162, 199, 391, 705, and 1993, both TCP and UDP Block incoming traffic destined for broadcast addresses and internal loopback addresses Disable stack execution For more information on these precautions, see [http://www.cert.org/advisories/CA-2002- 03.html] CERT Advisory 2002-03. Vulnerability Details: Service: snmp


root@server [~]# yum remove net-snmp-utils
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: net-snmp-utils
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * updates: centos.mirrors.tds.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Package(s) net-snmp-utils available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal

root@server [~]# yum remove net-snmp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: net-snmp
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * updates: centos.mirrors.tds.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Package(s) net-snmp available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal

root@server [~]# yum remove snmp    
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: snmp
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * updates: centos.mirrors.tds.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
No Packages marked for removal
```

Comment: Is port 161 open ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you tried to shutdown MYSQL server before remove ?
also please add add 'skip-networking' to /etc/my.cnf and restart your mysql server.